# SocialSharing Ionic4 Angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]Hello i am trying to do SocialSharing to my ionic4 Angular8 project. It works but only sends url param into facebook  This is my code

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';

private socialSharing: SocialSharing,

 shareMedia() {
this.socialSharing.share(this.mediaDetails.message, this.mediaDetails.title, 'https://rovespier.com/rovespier_api/api/uploads/' + this.mediaDetails.image_path, 'https://rovespier.com' + this.mediaDetails.msg_id)
  .then(() => {
  }).catch(() => {
  });
```

}

Comment: what exactly the issue? can you please explain it bit more

Comment: what should be the exact output?

Comment: It doesn't show the this.mediaDetails.title or the image. It should right?

Comment: yeah it should. but if you want to share specific on fb then you can use `shareViaFacebook` function as per its parameter

Comment: You mean shareViaFacebook(message: string, image?: string, url?: string):  in here? https://ionic.io/docs/premier-plugins/social-sharing.   i am getting error can not find message on first param

Comment: yeah exactly if you want to share specifically on facebook.

Comment: you mean like this right? this.mediaDetails.message, this.mediaDetails.title, 'https://rovespier.com/rovespier_api/api/uploads/' + this.mediaDetails.image_path, 'https://rovespier.com'+ this.mediaDetails.msg_id. Because when i put essage: this.mediaDetails.title, image?: 'https://rovespier.com/rovespier_api/api/uploads/' + this.mediaDetails.image_path, url?:'https://rovespier.com'+ this.mediaDetails.msg_id i am getting errors

Comment: what error can you show me

Comment: i updated with image see message, image? and url

Comment: you are using wrongly. Use the way I have shared in my answer., just pass the value. dont use message: image?: .

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use second parameter as **blank**, because first PARAM is for message and second PARAM is for title and while sharing on Facebook it use title.  so please modify your a bit like mentioned below.

```
this.socialSharing.share(this.mediaDetails.title,this.mediaDetails.title, 'https://rovespier.com/rovespier_api/api/uploads/' + this.mediaDetails.image_path, 'https://rovespier.com')
.then(() => {
}).catch(() => {
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Only give url last param on facebook. And via text message, the first param and the last

Comment: thanks man i am wating you are a life saver

Comment: As per the current code snippet . you are sending second parameter as null which you should not. Please update your code or may be you can schedule a google meet call or something we can figure it out